# Get all quarters in Month, Year format between two dates

Tags: sql-server, date

I have two dates say `'2011-01-23'` and `'2015-11-29'`,

- '2011-01-23' falls in first quarter of 2011 so `'Jan 2011'`
- '2015-11-29' falls in fourth quarter of 2015 so `'Oct 2015'`

In SQL Server I want get all quarters in a select list. 
e.g.

Input: `@StartDate='2011-01-23' , @EndDate='2015-11-29'`

Output:

```
Jan 2011
Apr 2011
Jul 2011
Oct 2011
Jan 2012
Apr 2012
Jul 2013
Oct 2013
Jan 2014
......
......
......
Jul 2015
Oct 2015
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the dates as follows:

```
declare @StartDate datetime
declare @EndDate datetime
select @StartDate='2011-01-23' , @EndDate='2015-11-29'

;With Quarters as (
    select DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,0,@StartDate),0) as dt
    union all
    select DATEADD(quarter,1,dt)
    from Quarters
    where dt < DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,0,@EndDate),0)
)
select
    --I'd usually keep them as dates at this point, but to match your requirement
    CONVERT(varchar(3),dt,109) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(4),dt,120)
from Quarters order by dt
```

This also uses a couple of other tricks - it uses [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with far too short target datatypes to quickly truncate the strings to just the parts that we want to keep - and it uses a [`DATEADD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)/`DATEDIFF` pair to quickly round a datetime value down to it's nearest interval boundary.

For SQL Server 2012, you could instead use [`FORMAT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) to produce the output string, but I've not experimented with that much so I'll leave that as an exercise...

Comment: Thank you very much Damien, Same solution I found on web.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution of my question..

```
WITH mycte AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2011-01-01' AS DATE) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATEADD(Q,1,DateValue)    FROM    mycte  WHERE   DATEADD(Q,1,DateValue) < '2012-12-31'
)

SELECT  CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(MONTH,DateValue))+ ' ' +Convert(varchar(4),DATEPART(YYYY,DateValue)) FROM  mycte OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: i'm looking for the same function in mysql  can you help me